# ListView does not refresh

Tags: java, android, listview

I'd like to create a ListView and add items dynamically. Here is my code:

CustomAdapter.java:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>{

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    LinearLayout linearMain;
    ArrayList<Item> data = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                              ArrayList<Item> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            linearMain = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.lineraMain);

            Item myImage = data.get(position);

            TextView label = new TextView(context);
            label.setText(myImage.name);
            linearMain.addView(label);

            ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
            int outImage = myImage.image;
            image.setImageResource(outImage);
            linearMain.addView(image);
        }
        return row;
    }
}
```

Item.java:

```
public class Item {

    int image;
    String name;

    public Item(int image, String name) {
        super();
        this.image = image;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

GallerF.java

```
 ArrayList<Item> imageArry = new ArrayList<Item>();
 CustomAdapter adapter;
 ListView dataList;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_gallery, parent, false);
    dataList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lista);

    return v;
}
.....
public void CreateNewListRow(){
    imageArry.add(new Item(R.drawable.ek_logo,name));
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list,imageArry);
    dataList.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lineraMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_gallery.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="hu.redbuttonebb.endi.fragmentek20.GalleryF"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:id="@+id/linlayout">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lista"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now when I run the app it's create one row with the correct picture and name. But when I'd like to create one more then nothing happen. Where do I do it wrong?

Comment: How do you add new items to the list ? Do you call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after you do that ?

Comment: I'm using this line to add new item `imageArry.add(new Item(R.drawable.ek_logo,name));` . And yes I call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` but you can see that above.

Comment: Yes, I can see that you're calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` when you set the adapter to the list but you also have to call it every time you modify the `imageArry` list.

Comment: `View row = convertView; if (row == null) { ... } return row;` where you are setting image when `convertView != null` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your file with this:

```
ArrayList<Item> imageArry = new ArrayList<Item>();
CustomAdapter adapter;
ListView dataList;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_gallery, parent, false);
dataList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lista);

adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list,imageArry);
dataList.setAdapter(adapter);

return v;
}
.....

public void CreateNewListRow(){
imageArry.add(new Item(R.drawable.ek_logo,name));
imageArry.add(new Item(R.drawable.ek_logo,name));
imageArry.add(new Item(R.drawable.ek_logo,name));
imageArry.add(new Item(R.drawable.ek_logo,name));
imageArry.add(new Item(R.drawable.ek_logo,name));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Edit your list.xml with below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lineraMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Remove ScrollView, ListView do not require ScrollView:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      tools:context="hu.redbuttonebb.endi.fragmentek20.GalleryF"
      android:background="@drawable/background"
      android:id="@+id/linlayout">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lista"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show your row item ie. list.xml .

Comment: This won't work, since you are not modifying the arraylist in the adapter, just the arraylist in the fragment. When you call notifyDataSetChanged, the adapter will still have the old items in the arraylist.

Comment: @Drv Thank you! I removed SrcollView and it's working now!!

Comment: @T.dog :)Good. Go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new Adapter every time you want to add an item. You need to create a method in your adapter and call that method when you add an item, like this:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>{

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
LinearLayout linearMain;
ArrayList<Item> data = new ArrayList<Item>();

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                          ArrayList<Item> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        linearMain = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.lineraMain);

        Item myImage = data.get(position);

        TextView label = new TextView(context);
        label.setText(myImage.name);
        linearMain.addView(label);

        ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
        int outImage = myImage.image;
        image.setImageResource(outImage);
        linearMain.addView(image);
    }
    return row;
}

public void addItem(Item item) {
    data.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and change your CreateNewListRow to this:

```
public void CreateNewListRow(){
    adapter.addItem(new Item(R.drawable.ek_logo,name));
}
```

and change your onCreate to this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_gallery, parent, false);
    dataList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lista);

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list,imageArry);
    dataList.setAdapter(adapter);

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing happed. It's the same.

Comment: I just tested this and it works. Can you share more code? Maybe there is an error somewhere else. And are you sure you changed all of the code i provided above?

Answer (score 1):

> Add this method to Adapter & extends Adapter to BaseAdapter

```
public class FriendsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Activity context;
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
LayoutInflater inflater;

public FriendsAdapter(Activity c) {

    context = c;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
}

public void add(String item) {

    try {
        data.add(item);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void remove(int position) {

    try {
        data.remove(data.get(position));

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_friends, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.tvUserName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvUserName);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    try {

        holder.tvUserName.setText(data.get(position));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {

    TextView tvUserName;

}}
```

> Initializing Adapter

```
FriendsAdaoter adapter = new FriendsAdapter(this);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.add("ABCDEFGHIJKL");
```

Comment: What is that tvUserName?

Comment: tvUserName is a textView of your listItem